# Does assigning a custom URLSessionDelegate override default behavior for methods that are not implemented?

Tags: swift, foundation, urlsession

In the documentation for `URLSessionDelegate` it says:

> Your URLSession object doesn’t need to have a delegate. If no delegate
>   is assigned, a system-provided delegate is used, and you must provide
>   a completion callback to obtain the data.

I only need to implement one of the methods like this:

```
class SessionDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
        var request = request
        request.httpMethod = task.originalRequest?.httpMethod ?? request.httpMethod
        completionHandler(request)
    }
}
```

And then initialize my session like this:

```
self.session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: SessionDelegate(), delegateQueue: nil)
```

Does that override any other behavior in the "system-provided delegate" for the methods that I didn't implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any (optional) functions you don't override in your `SessionDelegate` class will respect the default implementation behaviour of the original functions.

In order to check the default behaviour for each function, please see the documentation in the header files (option+click on URLSessionTaskDelegate) or here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate